# Software reformating SQL statements

Tags: windows, linux, sql, code-beautification

I'm looking for an easy tool which is helping to reformat SQL statements. So e.g.

```
SELECT foo, baa from baafoo where id > 10 and comment = 'John was it';
```

will become to something like

```
SELECT 
     foo, 
     baa 
FROM 
     baafoo 
WHERE 
     id > 10 
     and comment = 'John was it';
```

It's not about using a big tool like PowerDesigner or SQLWorkbench. Just a little straight forward one -- maybe command line based with reading from stdin and writing to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sql-format.com/ lets you format things with quite a lot of control if you can cope with a web interface rather than a command-line tool:

[image]

Comment: Looks good, but would like to have something offline.

Comment: Yup - we don't recommend web sites here (having said that, I upvoted this, as it useful for me to know ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I like the [SQLBeautifier](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SqlBeautifier) plugin for [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/). SublimeText is cross-platform (Windows, Linux, and OSX) and has a free trial with unlimited functionality. The plugin itself is free and open source (MIT Licensed). Installation is quite simple - just run installer for SublimeText, open SublimeText and install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation), then in Sublime Text type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and select `Package Control:Install Packages` then select SQLBeautifier.

I've used it and like i,t however it may not be quite what you're looking for so another good option is the back-end behind it; [SQLParse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/) python (2 or 3) library. The library is [open sourced](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/master/COPYING) and free.

If you would prefer a web-app SQLParse is [also hosted online](http://sqlformat.org/). Or if you want an HTTP API that is [available as well](http://sqlformat.org/api/) - free with a 500 requests/hr limit.

All of those will provide the same output (if given the same options that is ofc). It is *slightly* different than the one you showed:

```
SELECT FOO,
       BAA
FROM BAAFOO
WHERE ID > 10
  AND COMMENT = 'John was it';
```

Comment: Using Geany. Maybe possible to port as it's Python ...